# Compiling and running ARM assembly binary on Cortex-M4 (simulated in QEMU)

Tags: arm, qemu, cortex-m

I successfully compiled and executed ARM binary file on a virtual QEMU embedded system `connex` using this procedure:

```
arm-none-eabi-as -o program.o program.s
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x0 -o program.elf program.o  
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary program.elf program.bin
dd if=/dev/zero of=flash.bin bs=4096 count=4096
dd if=program.bin of=flash.bin bs=4096 conv=notrunc
qemu-system-arm -M connex -pflash flash.bin -nographic -serial /dev/null
```

In line four I created a zeroed out empty disk which represents flash and in line five I copied my binary into flash.

So this works like a charm, but it simulates an entire embedded system while I only want to simulate ARM core, for example Cortex-M4. This is why I am trying to just use `qemu-arm` instead of `qemu-system-arm`.

So I 1st tried to compile and run my program like this (lines 1-3 are same as above):

```
arm-none-eabi-as -o program.o program.s
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x0 -o program.elf program.o  
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary program.elf program.bin
qemu-arm -cpu cortex-m4 program.bin
```

And this doesn't work - it says:

```
Error while loading program.bin: Exec format error
```

So I tried to create flash image like before (because it worked):

```
arm-none-eabi-as -o program.o program.s
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x0 -o program.elf program.o  
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary program.elf program.bin
dd if=/dev/zero of=flash.bin bs=4096 count=4096
dd if=program.bin of=flash.bin bs=4096 conv=notrunc
qemu-arm -cpu cortex-m4 flash.bin
```

And I get this:

```
Error while loading flash.bin: Permission denied
```

Can anyone help me a bit? Using `sudo` doesn't help.

Comment: qemu-arm will start in ARM mode if the ELF entry point has the low bit clear, and Thumb mode if the entry point has the low bit set (usual convention for Thumb mode ELF files). For an M profile core if you try to execute anything with CPSR.T not set you'll get an immediate UsageFault (which in qemu-arm will probably manifest as attempting to deliver a SIGILL). It won't actually execute anything as an ARM instruction, though the debug log disassembler probably still disassembles the insns in ARM format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

qemu-arm's purpose is not "simulate just an ARM core". It is "run a single *Linux* binary", and it expects that the binary file you provide it is a Linux format ELF executable. Trying to feed it something else is not going to work.

Since Linux assumes A-profile cores, not M-profile cores, anything you do with -cpu cortex-m4 on qemu-arm will only be working by luck, not deliberately. (We don't disable those CPU types since there are some GCC test case scenarios that use semihosting which sort-of-work and which we don't want to deliberately break. But those are working as much by luck as anything else.)

Comment: why does qemu-arm then have an assortment of cortex-m cores where qemu-system-arm doesnt?  is there no connection between the two (does qemu-arm use different code/cores than qemu-system-arm)?

Comment: qemu-system-arm supports the same set of CPUs, which includes cortex-m3 and cortex-m4. If your qemu-system-arm doesn't list cortex-m3 then it must be a very old version (a decade or more out of date). Or possibly it's a distro-specific special with a lot of the code disabled -- I think RedHat have one of those for running ARM virtual machines, where most of the emulation-only cores are disabled to minimise the security attack surface.

Comment: As of the last time I checked there wasnt a system with cortex-m4 or anything (M) but cortex-m3, as pointed out...There is a fork that takes advantage of them, yes.

Comment: the cortex-m3 in qemu was only recently fixed to not be broken, so even though it was added when the tiva c was called stellaris and was from luminary micro before texas instruments assumilated them.  actually they were the first ones to have an m3 in silicon (for mass consumption) and the qemu backend goes that far, but has been buggy that long.  who knows without tryhing the m4, etc qemu targets may also be buggy until someone goes and actually tries them.

Comment: Upstream has m3 and m4, and has had m3 for a very long time, so if your binary does not say it has m3 then it is either ancient or a fork or otherwise has had stuff disabled. I agree that upstream M3 was a bit broken until recently, so best to go with QEMU 2.9 or 2.10. But even older QEMU versions listed the CPUs in qemu-system-arm as well as qemu-arm.

Comment: I just pulled from the repo and dont see an m4 system, I see a number of m3s.  Please point out the m4 system. (I see also you are a or the maintainer of qemu)...

Comment: Yeah, we have the m4 CPU support, but no board model for an M4 yet. Passing -cpu cortex-m4 to one of the stellaris boards will probably produce a frankenstein thing that sort of works.

Comment: I fully understand someone has to be motivated enough to put in the work and that hasnt happened yet.  and yes the m3 and m4 are both armv7m with the bulk of the thumb2 extensions so m3 is fairly close to a m4 from a learning the instruction set in an emulator perspective.

Comment: Adding an M4 MPS2 board would be pretty easy, but as you say it's not too clear that it would be worthwhile until we implement floating point.

Comment: @old_timer: you might be interested in https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/qemu/ which is a fork that has more focus on cortex-m cores

Answer (score 1):

Compared to a microcontroller build you need an entry point (and it ram).

start.s

```
.thumb
.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
    @mov r0,=0x10000
    @mov sp,r0
    bl notmain
    mov r7,#0x1
    mov r0,#0
    swi #0
.word 0xFFFFFFFF
    b .

.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl write
write:
    push {r7,lr}
    mov r7,#0x04
    swi 0
    pop {r7,pc}
    b .

.end
```

notmain.c

```
void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int GET32 ( unsigned int );
void dummy ( unsigned int );
void write ( unsigned int, char *, unsigned int );
int notmain ( void )
{
    //unsigned int ra;
    //for(ra=0;ra<1000;ra++) dummy(ra);
    write(1,"Hello\n",6);
    return(0);

}
```

hello.ld

```
ENTRY(_start)
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x00010000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > ram
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

build

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings start.s -o start.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding  -mthumb -c notmain.c -o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -o notmain.elf -T hello.ld start.o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy notmain.elf notmain.bin -O binary
```

run

```
qemu-arm -d in_asm,cpu,cpu_reset -D hello -cpu cortex-m4 notmain.elf 
Hello
```

dump log

```
cat hello
CPU Reset (CPU 0)
R00=00000000 R01=00000000 R02=00000000 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00000000 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=00000000 R14=00000000 R15=00000000
PSR=40000000 -Z-- A usr26
CPU Reset (CPU 0)
R00=00000000 R01=00000000 R02=00000000 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00000000 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=00000000 R14=00000000 R15=00000000
PSR=40000010 -Z-- A usr32
Reserved 0xf7000000 bytes of guest address space
host mmap_min_addr=0x10000
guest_base  0x7f4347fb4000
start    end      size     prot
00010000-00011000 00001000 r-x
f67ff000-f6800000 00001000 ---
f6800000-f7000000 00800000 rw-
start_brk   0x00000000
end_code    0x00010044
start_code  0x00010000
start_data  0x00010044
end_data    0x00010044
start_stack 0xf6fff350
brk         0x00010044
entry       0x00010001
----------------
IN: 
0x00010000:  f000 f810  bl  0x10024

R00=00000000 R01=f6fff4c2 R02=00000000 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00010044 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=f6fff350 R14=00000000 R15=00010000
PSR=00000030 ---- T usr32
----------------
IN: notmain
0x00010024:  b508       push    {r3, lr}
0x00010026:  2001       movs    r0, #1
0x00010028:  4903       ldr r1, [pc, #12]   (0x10038)
0x0001002a:  2206       movs    r2, #6
0x0001002c:  f7ff fff5  bl  0x1001a

R00=00000000 R01=f6fff4c2 R02=00000000 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00010044 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=f6fff350 R14=00010005 R15=00010024
PSR=00000030 ---- T usr32
----------------
IN: 
0x0001001a:  b580       push    {r7, lr}
0x0001001c:  2704       movs    r7, #4
0x0001001e:  df00       svc 0

R00=00000001 R01=0001003c R02=00000006 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00010044 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=f6fff348 R14=00010031 R15=0001001a
PSR=00000030 ---- T usr32
----------------
IN: 
0x00010020:  bd80       pop {r7, pc}

R00=00000006 R01=0001003c R02=00000006 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000004
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00010044 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=f6fff340 R14=00010031 R15=00010020
PSR=00000030 ---- T usr32
----------------
IN: notmain
0x00010030:  2000       movs    r0, #0
0x00010032:  bc08       pop {r3}
0x00010034:  bc02       pop {r1}
0x00010036:  4708       bx  r1

R00=00000006 R01=0001003c R02=00000006 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00010044 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=f6fff348 R14=00010031 R15=00010030
PSR=00000030 ---- T usr32
----------------
IN: 
0x00010004:  2701       movs    r7, #1
0x00010006:  2000       movs    r0, #0
0x00010008:  df00       svc 0

R00=00000000 R01=00010005 R02=00000006 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00010044 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=f6fff350 R14=00010031 R15=00010004
PSR=40000030 -Z-- T usr32
```

It gets unhappy if you touch the stack pointer, so dont...

Thanks for pointing out this program, wasnt aware of it, going to have some fun with it...

EDIT

sorry you just wanted assembly.

start.s

```
.thumb
.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
    mov r4,#10
top:
    nop
    sub r4,#1
    bne top

    mov r7,#0x1
    mov r0,#0
    swi #0
.word 0xFFFFFFFF
    b .

.end
```

linker script above

build

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings start.s -o start.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -o notmain.elf -T hello.ld start.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy notmain.elf notmain.bin -O binary
```

run

```
qemu-arm -d in_asm,cpu,cpu_reset -D hello -cpu cortex-m4 notmain.elf
```

dump log

```
cat hello
CPU Reset (CPU 0)
R00=00000000 R01=00000000 R02=00000000 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00000000 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=00000000 R14=00000000 R15=00000000
PSR=40000000 -Z-- A usr26
CPU Reset (CPU 0)
R00=00000000 R01=00000000 R02=00000000 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00000000 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=00000000 R14=00000000 R15=00000000
PSR=40000010 -Z-- A usr32
Reserved 0xf7000000 bytes of guest address space
host mmap_min_addr=0x10000
guest_base  0x7f36110fc000
start    end      size     prot
00010000-00011000 00001000 r-x
f67ff000-f6800000 00001000 ---
f6800000-f7000000 00800000 rw-
start_brk   0x00000000
end_code    0x00010014
start_code  0x00010000
start_data  0x00010014
end_data    0x00010014
start_stack 0xf6fff350
brk         0x00010014
entry       0x00010001
----------------
IN: 
0x00010000:  240a       movs    r4, #10
0x00010002:  46c0       nop         (mov r8, r8)
0x00010004:  3c01       subs    r4, #1
0x00010006:  d1fc       bne.n   0x10002

R00=00000000 R01=f6fff4c2 R02=00000000 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00010014 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=f6fff350 R14=00000000 R15=00010000
PSR=00000030 ---- T usr32
----------------
IN: 
0x00010002:  46c0       nop         (mov r8, r8)
0x00010004:  3c01       subs    r4, #1
0x00010006:  d1fc       bne.n   0x10002

R00=00000000 R01=f6fff4c2 R02=00000000 R03=00000000
R04=00000009 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00010014 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=f6fff350 R14=00000000 R15=00010002
PSR=20000030 --C- T usr32
R00=00000000 R01=f6fff4c2 R02=00000000 R03=00000000
R04=00000008 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00010014 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=f6fff350 R14=00000000 R15=00010002
PSR=20000030 --C- T usr32
----------------
IN: 
0x00010008:  2701       movs    r7, #1
0x0001000a:  2000       movs    r0, #0
0x0001000c:  df00       svc 0

R00=00000000 R01=f6fff4c2 R02=00000000 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00010014 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=f6fff350 R14=00000000 R15=00010008
PSR=60000030 -ZC- T usr32
```

Comment: re-reading your title you wanted assembly, remove the bl notmain and the gcc part.

Comment: This is making Linux syscalls from M profile code, which only really works by accident, and doesn't correspond to code for any real-hardware RTOS as far as I know... You'd be better off using qemu-system-arm and semihosting (or talking to the UART) in my opinion. In qemu-arm there will be no interrupt controller, no access to any of the memory mapped system registers, no handling of exceptions, and no UART or timer device. These are all pretty important for M-profile code.

Comment: If you want to use cortex-m4 or the others (with the exception of the m3) there isnt a choice yet with with qemu-system-arm, that is a bigger project to go write a system add it to qemu-system-arm to play with this simulator.

Comment: in no way shape or form is it an accident a call is a call, nothing magical about them, linux is just a collection of instructions as is this.  I could have left the calls out, added them for fun.  OP wanted to know how to do this, you provided the missing link

Comment: I'm the upstream QEMU ARM maintainer, and I am telling you that it is accidental. qemu-arm is for Linux binaries. It doesn't have any code that specifically says "we will stop with an error if you pass us an M profile core", but it's not intentional that it has a particular behaviour, because M profile and Linux don't make much sense together. It's an accident if it does something helpful.

Comment: then why is it in the qemu-arm list if it is something not expected to work?  that seems like a pretty big bug.

Comment: if qemu-system-arm had an m4 (I know someone has to have the desire to want to make that happen) and qemu-arm didnt list a number of cortex-ms this question wouldnt have needed to be asked...

Comment: Like I said, it's there by accident, and because we don't want to deliberately break GCC test suites and other users who happen to have found it works for their limited purposes. It's not a very big bug, because all the things that are supposed to work work fine. We just don't happen to diagnose user error as nicely as we perhaps could.