# C array not initialized as expected when cross-compiling for baremetal ARM

Tags: arrays, c, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

My aim here is to implement a simple baremetal program for ARM, compile it manually and analyze it in GDB.
A simple example `main.c` that shows my problem is:

```
int main(){
    int a[5] = {0};

    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 2;
    a[2] = 3;
    a[3] = 4;
    a[4] = 5;

    return 0;
}
```

This is how I compile it:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -g main.c
arm-none-eabi-ld main.o -o main.elf
```

Run it in QEMU:

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -nographic -kernel main.elf -S -s
```

When I use `print` or `display` in GDB, I always get `a = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`. I can put the assignments in loop or do something else with the array. GDB shows `a = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}` both before and after the assignments.

When I compile the code for x86 and run it natively, there's no problem.

This is quite complicated so I considered a few things that could be the reason:

1. The code is wrong,
2. The compilation process / usage of the toolchain is wrong,
3. QEMU is used the wrong way
4. The program works well, but GDB shows wrong values

I excluded (1.) because it works on x86. To exclude (2.) I looked into `objdump` of the ELF file, part of which can be seen here:

```
    a[1] = 2;
    8030:   e3a03002    mov r3, #2
    8034:   e50b3014    str r3, [fp, #-20]  ; 0xffffffec
    a[2] = 3;
    8038:   e3a03003    mov r3, #3
    803c:   e50b3010    str r3, [fp, #-16]
```

It really looks like the values are actually assigned to the elements of the array.

To exclude (4.) I compiled the latest GDB with support for all available targets. (`GNU gdb (GDB) 11.0.50.20210521-git`)

QEMU and GCC are taken from Ubuntu packages `qemu-system-arm`, `gcc-arm-none-eabi`.

**Why do the results differ from what I expect?** Does any of (1. - 4.) make sense as a potential root of the problem? I'm trying to actually understand the logic behind this, not only to have an array.

Edit0:

Responding to paxdiablo's idea about entry point:
I get this warning from ld:
`arm-none-eabi-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000008000`
And this address is actually where `main` is stored.

Regarding the topic of creating an unused, hence optimized-out array, mentioned by Eric Postpischil:
I've checked the results with `volatile` keyword, and also used `-O0` option of GCC. These, unfortunately, did not change anything.

The whole assembly, retrieved by using `-S` option for `gcc` is:

```
    .cpu arm7tdmi
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1
    .eabi_attribute 26, 1
    .eabi_attribute 30, 6
    .eabi_attribute 34, 0
    .eabi_attribute 18, 4
    .file   "test.c"
    .text
    .section    .rodata
    .align  2
.LC0:
    .word   1
    .word   2
    .word   3
    .word   4
    .text
    .align  2
    .global main
    .arch armv4t
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu softvfp
    .type   main, %function
main:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 16
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    str fp, [sp, #-4]!
    add fp, sp, #0
    sub sp, sp, #20
    ldr r3, .L3
    sub ip, fp, #20
    ldm r3, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
    stm ip, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
    mov r3, #5
    str r3, [fp, #-20]
    mov r3, #4
    str r3, [fp, #-16]
    mov r3, #3
    str r3, [fp, #-12]
    mov r3, #2
    str r3, [fp, #-8]
    mov r3, #0
    mov r0, r3
    add sp, fp, #0
    @ sp needed
    ldr fp, [sp], #4
    bx  lr
.L4:
    .align  2
.L3:
    .word   .LC0
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (15:9-2019-q4-0ubuntu1) 9.2.1 20191025 (release) [ARM/arm-9-branch revision 277599]"
```

Edit1:
As mentioned in the comments, one can view the address of the array in GDB, and then dump the memory, instead of asking for `print a`.
I've used `print &a` and `x 0xffffffe8` (this is the address I got), but apparently the result is the same - the array a holds zeros before and after the 'assignments'.

Comment: The program as shown does not “do” anything. The only things a C program “does,” as specified by the C standard are the *observable behavior*. That includes writing to files, input/output interaction, and access to volatile objects. Your program does not have any of that, so the compiler is not required to generate code to do anything at all with `a`. Change `int a[5]` to `volatile int a[5]` and see what happens.

Comment: The fact you see assembly code that appears to be storing the desired values somewhere is interesting, as it suggests the compiler is generating code to initialize `a`. But maybe that is not what the code is doing. Maybe that is just some preparatory code, and the code that would store the values in the memory formally reserved for `a`, as reported to gdb, was optimized away. So gdb never sees the values. Maybe changing compiler optimization settings would result in different behavior.

Comment: @Eric, that seems unlikely, given the objdump is showing the values `2` and `3` being placed on the stack an integer apart, as it would for populating the array. I agree that the whole thing *could* be optimised away but, from the question, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: The problem originated from a code that actually somewhat made use of the array (for example it was passed as an argument to other functions) and the results were the same. I've also used `volatile` and disabled optimization in GCC, the problem remains

Comment: I'd be adding a possible point 5.  What is the entry point of a kernel run by qemu-system-arm? Generally, compiling C code brings in a slew of stuff to set up the C runtime environment, things like `crt0` and the standard library. This means the entry point is usually something like `_start` rather than `_main` and the former calls the latter once everything is prepped. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128604/compiling-and-running-arm-assembly-binary-on-cortex-m4-simulated-in-qemu

Comment: Show the entire generated assembly (use `-S` with the compiler, not just `objdump`) and show the command line you compile with. Also state the complete compiler name and version. (When you use `-S`, the compiler will put generated assembly in the output file. If you have a `-o` switch, it will go there, so you might want to change that from `-o something.o` to `-o something.s` or remove it.)

Comment: Also ask gdb to show the address of `a`, and then dump the memory there, rather than just asking it to print the array `a`.

Comment: Observe those memory references where the instructions are storing 5, 4, 3, and 2: `[fp, #-20]`, `[fp, #-16]`, `[fp, #-12]`, and `[fp, #-8]`. Those are ascending locations, so they cannot be the elements of the array that you initialize with 5, 4, 3, and 2 (`a[4]`, `a[3]`, `a[2]`, and `a[1]`, because those are descending elements). So the compiler is doing something else with those instructions, not initializing `a`. Also, I bet the address you saw for `a`, 0xffffffe8, does not overlap those addresses. (Show the fp register to see.)

Comment: What version of gcc is this?  The asm output is very strange.  With the arm-none-eabi-gcc from Ubuntu 20.04, reporting as `gcc version 9.2.1 20191025 (release) [ARM/arm-9-branch revision 277599] (15:9-2019-q4-0ubuntu1)`, I see asm that looks much more sensible.  So I can't reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: Is there any chance you are compiling a different `main.c` than you have posted here?  Maybe forgetting to save your source file in your editor, so you're still compiling a previous version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is:

*2) The compilation process / usage of the toolchain is wrong.*

You may have several problems, an important one being that the use of the `-kernel` option requires the start address of your program to be `0x00010000`.
And you don't have a startup file, nor a linker script.

The following example should work fine, and is just adapted from a [seminal article](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/hello-world-for-bare-metal-arm-using-qemu/) from Francesco Balducci on his [blog](https://balau82.wordpress.com/).

startup.s:

```
.global _Reset
_Reset:
 LDR sp, =stack_top
 BL c_entry
 B .
```

test.ld:

```
ENTRY(_Reset)
SECTIONS
{
 . = 0x10000;
 .startup . : { startup.o(.text) }
 .text : { *(.text) }
 .data : { *(.data) }
 .bss : { *(.bss COMMON) }
 . = ALIGN(8);
 . = . + 0x1000; /* 4kB of stack memory */
 stack_top = .;
}
```

test.c:

```
volatile unsigned int * const UART0DR = (unsigned int *)0x101f1000;
 
void print_uart0(const char *s) {
 while(*s != '\0') { /* Loop until end of string */
 *UART0DR = (unsigned int)(*s); /* Transmit char */
 s++; /* Next char */
 }
}
 
void c_entry() {
    int a[5] = {0};

    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 2;
    a[2] = 3;
    a[3] = 4;
    a[4] = 5;

    if (a[0] == 1 && a[1] == 2 && a[2] == 3 && a[3] == 4 && a[4] == 5) {
        print_uart0("Hello world!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

build.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-
QEMU_SYSTEM_ARM=/opt/qemu-6.0.0/bin/qemu-system-arm

${CROSS_COMPILE}as -mcpu=arm926ej-s -g startup.s -o startup.o
${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc -c -mcpu=arm926ej-s -g test.c -o test.o
${CROSS_COMPILE}ld -T test.ld test.o startup.o -o test.elf

${QEMU_SYSTEM_ARM} -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel test.elf
```

execution: (fixing the compilation warnings and disabling sound emulation is out of the scope of the current answer)

./build.sh

```
test.c: In function 'c_entry':
test.c:23:12: warning: 'return' with a value, in function returning void
   23 |     return 0;
      |            ^
test.c:10:6: note: declared here
   10 | void c_entry() {
      |      ^~~~~~~
pulseaudio: set_sink_input_volume() failed
pulseaudio: Reason: Invalid argument
pulseaudio: set_sink_input_mute() failed
pulseaudio: Reason: Invalid argument
Hello world!
```